# Adding WSDL to project creates only types, no entry to app.config and throws three errors

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, visual-studio-2013, wsdl

I'm trying to add service reference to my (.NET 4.6) project.
When I choose `Add Service Reference` and add URL of WSDL I can see it is correctly discovered:
[image]

I've unchecked `Reuse types in all referenced assemblies` as shown below:
[image]

But when I click `OK` I get three warnings in Error List window:

Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Serialization.StructMapping' to type 'System.Xml.Serialization.MembersMapping'.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://bik.pl/cc/big']/wsdl:portType[@name='BIG']

Warning 3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://bik.pl/cc/big']/wsdl:binding[@name='BIGBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://bik.pl/cc/big']/wsdl:service[@name='BIG']/wsdl:port[@name='BIG']

Warning 2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://bik.pl/cc/big']/wsdl:portType[@name='BIG']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://bik.pl/cc/big']/wsdl:binding[@name='BIGBinding']

I've tried different options while importing, but I get those errors all the time.
I've validated WSDL using [www.wsdl-analyzer.com](http://www.wsdl-analyzer.com) but it shows no error:
[image]

Here is quality report: https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/qualityReport/show/1784995829?version=1

SoapUI correctly shows all operations and I'm able to do them from SoapUI, but I need to add reference to my project in Visual Studio.

Below are links to WSDL and XSD:

https://wasstt.infomonitor.pl/39D97477-0709-455f-A7C8-6498B600AC5A/ws/BIG/WEB-INF/wsdl/dluznik.wsdl

https://wasstt.infomonitor.pl/39D97477-0709-455f-A7C8-6498B600AC5A/ws/BIG/WEB-INF/wsdl/dluznik.xsd

How can I import this WSDL into my project? I'm unable to modify structure of that WSDL, so I must use it as it is.

**EDIT:**
I've installed XMLSpy and opened that WSDL in it. After opening I got message saying that WSDL is valid.

Comment: are there any complex types defined in your wsdl?

Comment: @OzanGunceler I've just opened WSDL and XSD and yes, there are complex types (xs:complexType) You can see them in XSD

Comment: @OzanGunceler I've used similar WSDL's in past and they had even more complex objects (types) required and returned by methods. Problem with this WSDL is that I can't import it correctly

Comment: It appears your first warning is throwing your following two warnings. There is another question with a similar failure that may help you, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727339/wcf-service-cannot-serialize-custom-class-which-contains-an-exception-type-as-m) , with links in the answer. This would focus around the casting issue displayed in warning 1.

Comment: Also, this functions without issue on .Net 4.5 and fails on .Net 4.6. Are you able to change your Target framework to .Net 4.5 and verify this is the source of the issue?

Comment: @vipersassassin I can create new application even in .NET 4 if needed, I just need to generate that proxy without warnings

Comment: Mine was a windows form using .Net 4.5, no warnings generated

Comment: @vipersassassin Coud You please pack wsdl.exe wsdl and xsd You used and share those? I've reinstalled .NET and I am considering reinstalling VS. BTW I'm on Win10, but that should't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the problem has already been solved in a different way (other technology, resignation from the contract), but if you are still interested, the problem is that wsdl.exe don't support  circular reference in element definition.

```
<xs:element name="raport-z-rej-zap">
    <xs:complexType>
    <!-- ... -->
        <xs:element ref="tns:raport-z-rej-zap" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <!-- ... -->
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

All You need is to define named complex type insted of anonymous:

```
<xs:element name="raport-z-rej-zap" type="tns:Raport-z-rej-zap">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Struktura raportow z Rejestru Zapytan (ref. 6.6)</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="Raport-z-rej-zap">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="naglowek" type="tns:TypNaglowekRaportu" />
            <xs:element name="pytajacy" type="tns:TypDanePodmiotuPytajacego" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="dane-zap" type="tns:TypDaneZapytaniaZRejZap" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="uwagi-i-ostrz" type="tns:TypUwagOstrzezen" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="podmiot" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="dane-podm" type="tns:TypDanePodmiotu" />
                        <xs:element name="tresc-rap" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Tresc uprzednio przekazanego raportu</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:choice>
                                    <xs:element ref="tns:raport-fin" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                    <xs:element ref="tns:raport-dok" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                    <xs:element name="raport-z-rej-zap" type="tns:Raport-z-rej-zap" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                </xs:choice>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="suma-kontr" type="tns:TypSumaKontrolna" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="blad-przetw" type="tns:TypBladPrzetw" />
        <xs:element name="blad-struktury" type="tns:TypKomunikatAdministracyjny">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>zadanie operacji na bazie danych odrzucone z powodu bledow struktury (rezultat = blad struktury).</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="certyfikat" type="tns:TypRaportCertyfikat" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Or delete from wsdl element:

```
<wsdl:operation name="pobranie-raportu-z-rej-zap">
```

AFAIK You can't call this operation - it is reserved for BIG Infomonitor use.

Comment: Thank You for reply. I solved this by removing operations I don't need (I manually edited wsdl) and generating classes using svcutil. This was easier for me then. I tried contacting with BIG Informonitor to ask them to fix this, but got no response.

Comment: Sad think is most of BIG's (ERIF, KRD, CRIF, DZ) use Java on backend and their WSDL's works fine with Java frontend, but not always with .NET.
Ideally BIG's should update their WSDL files, but that's just a dream :) 
Dzięki!

Comment: Did You contact BIG Infomonitor with this problem? Maybe if more .NET developers will contact them finally they will fix that WSDL definition.

Answer (score 1):

WSDL it's correctly defined, that's why all analyzers are you giving correct answer. The main problem but it's that uses some objects referenced at https://www.bik.pl/cc/, that seems it's not serving that objects correctly, or cannot be accessed statically, and that's why appears that warnings at the webservice reference load.

As wsdl just got definitions of structure of methods & types used in an WS request, there's no real need to load it dinamically. So, yo can download the WSDL file, modify it if you're in need, and then charge it in VS. 
Anyway, I'm suspecting that you can use that webservice ignoring that warnings. Had you tried it?

Comment: Yes I've tried that, but Visual Studio isn't generating proxy class, just types,  so I can't call any method directly. I can download that WSDL and I'd like to modify it in a way I'll be able to add it to my project but I don't what I must change. I need that proxy class, without it there Is no way to call methods.

Comment: Can You show how I must change WSDL? Just a single method. Having this would help me updating others.

Comment: Althought accessing to https://www.bik.pl/cc/ it's giving Security connection errors (302 - Security redirect to a 404 page)...should you need  any kind of client certificate or http basic authenticaction to use this WS? As well, I should try to call some of the methods first using SOAP UI, so this way discover is there's any more security restriction.

Comment: As a final solution, you can always use HttpRequest to generate same POST to service, adding the SOAPAction headers, etc, and will act same ways as if a proxy class was generated automatically.

Comment: Some methods need credentials, buy I thought I don't need any to create proxy. SoapUi discovers methods and types fine, probably from XSD. Did You look at XSD, it contains types definition. Maybe WSDL.exe isn't using that XSD or maybe it has some errors.

Comment: HttpRequest might be an option but this way I must serialize and desetialize request and response manually and of course create every request manually.  Proxy would do that for me, that's the main advantage of adding service reference in VS.

Comment: I understand methods use credentials, but I dont believe are needed to retrieve wsdl correctly. I think your main problem it's that that WSDL its not WCF compliant, althought it's created in a Java environment. The main part you should change WSDL is in the retrieve of the schemas & primary namespaces. Let me add another answer so here doesnt is enought space.

Comment: You can edit Your current answer if needed. If You could show me how to edit that WSDL  I will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change this part, at the first of the wsdl file, replacing references to http://bik.pl/cc/big with some ones equivalents, or if you could access to that definitions in some other way, then save them to file & change wsdl to access to your saved files. For example, we see that you got dluznik.xsd. As well, if you see some namespaces are not beign used anymore in the wsdl, you can, directly, try to remove it.

Anyway, as told in my last comment, I think that problem it's just WSDL it's not Microsoft WCF compliant.

PD : Had you tried to use contract agreement when retrieving service reference? Difference using proxy classes will be just using generated objects for request/response, but it will be more contraint using that WS.

```
   <wsdl:definitions name="big" targetNamespace=**"http://bik.pl/cc/big"** 
xsi:schemaLocation=**"http://bik.pl/cc/big big.xsd"** xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tns2="http://bik.pl/cc/big/internal" xmlns:tns=**"http://bik.pl/cc/big"** xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ws="http://www.example.com/webservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://bik.pl/cc/big/internal" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xsd:import namespace="http://bik.pl/cc/big" schemaLocation="dluznik.xsd"/>
         <xs:element name="brak-odp-od-im" type="xs:string"/>
      </xsd:schema>
      <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xsd:import namespace=**"http://bik.pl/cc/big"** schemaLocation="dluznik.xsd"/>
      </xsd:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
```

Comment: Thank You for this. I'll test it as soon as possible and if this works and bounty expires I'll start it again just to award You! Thanks for help!

Comment: Hello again. Had noted that in wsdl appear http://bik.pl/cc/big, etc as simple http, but if you realize a curl, it gots a 301 Moved permanently to same version https, and that again redirects by security reasons to 404. It is possible that you must be whitelisted to use that WS? Anyway, you can at first try to edit that http://bik.pl/cc/big to it's https counterparts and try again...

Comment: Here the curl to http :nnn@debian:~$ curl -kI "h_t_t_p://www.bik.pl/cc/big/internal" -v --tlsv1 => HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: h_t_t_p_s://w_w_w.bik.pl/cc/big/internal

Comment: And the curl to https_://www.bik.pl/cc/big/internal : curl -kI "https://www.bik.pl/cc/big/internal" -v --tlsv1 -> < HTTP/1.1 302 Security Redirect

Answer (score 0):

Your target resource was produced for .Net 4.5. You will either have to choose a new target location with the applicable .Net you wish to use for a service reference, or install a local copy of the wdsl.exe to your machine.

Reinstall .NET Framework 4.6 and install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack. Then use wsdl.exe which is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools
```

Compile the proxy class into an assembly file and reference it in your project. Add missing assemblies if needed (i.e. `System.Web.Services.dll`).

Comment: Thank You so much for this. I'll check that right away!

Comment: @Misiu No problem, I think your easiest path though would be to change your target framework to .Net 4.5 and reload, but only if that is allowable by the rest of your code.

Comment: I've just created new console app with target framework set to `.NET Framework 4.5` and I still get same warnings when trying to add reference to that WSDL. I've tried that in VS2013 and VS2015. You didn't get those errors? You have entries in app.config and You can create instance of that proxy class?

Comment: How did You generate that class? from VS or with WSDL.exe?

Comment: Using VS'15 I added in the service reference using target framework .Net4.5. When switch over to .Net 4.6, I experienced the same issue as you. The class was generated through developer command prompt in VS'15

Comment: Could You please add exact command You used? I've just tried that with wsdl.exe from location You mentioned and I got error. when I start wsdl.exe I get info about .NET version 4.6.81.0

Comment: you need to add in the wsdl, then xsd from the url that you pasted earlier. The data generated when typing it in without any options or info will just tell you about the options and data needed, similar to a help file

Comment: I just did that and I still get error about StructMapping to MembersMapping casting. Here are steps I took. I've created new folder, copier wsdl.exe from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools` then I've downloaded both wsdl file and xsd to that folder and then using command prompt I used this command: `wsdl dluznik.wsdl dluznik.xsd`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127750/discussion-between-vipersassassin-and-misiu).